# CakePHP excel download troubleshooting

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298741/cakephp-excel-csv-export-component) to export data to excel but when I click the download link it just says "Server Error. May be down for maintenance....etc"

The only thing I had to change from the tutorial is the name of the Csv helper. The tutorial specifies "Csv.php" but I had to name it "CsvHelper.php". When I print the variable that goes to this view, it displays the array. However, when I remove this and just have the code listed exactly as it appears in that linked post from above I get a server error

```
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

These are the files that I had to add to my server as directed by the "tutorial"

```
//Helper
/App/View/Helper/CsvHelper.php

//Vendor
/App/Vendor/excel/PHPExcel.PHP
/App/Vendor/excel/PHPExcel/    //contains the rest of PHPExcel

//view
/App/View/Orders/download.ctp  //Tutorial specifies /App/View/Homes/download.ctp so I made sure to change the link accordingly in the view which actually "links" to this
```

As I mentioned previously when I print the array on download.ctp see this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Order] => Array ( [id] => 1 [userid] => 2 [order_status] => completed [email] => test@gmail.com [total] => 8.00 ) )
```

My array's structure matches that of the tutorial which is

```
$orders[0]['Order'];
```

Is there something I have to configure with CakePHP for downloading files? I have no idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 3):

Outputting different types of content in cake 2.x is now easy and a "piece of cake" :)

View classes can easily be switched to whatever output you need (json, xml, csv, ..).
In your case I would use https://github.com/josegonzalez/CsvView .

```
$this->viewClass = 'CsvView.Csv';
```

and export the data as documented in the plugin readme.

Comment: Could you expand your answer to include info how to use it if the developer wants to deliver it by file extension in the URL like /posts/view/1.csv, /posts/view/1.json, /posts/view/1.xml?