# cakephp export data into excel or Csv file

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, export-to-excel, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x .. i am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298741/cakephp-excel-csv-export-component) solution for exporting data into excel sheet .. the problem is i dont know how can i add the column names or headings and then put data under  the columns  ..

for example here is what i am doing at the moment

```
$this->CSV->addRow(array_keys($line));
 foreach ($Contacts as $contact)
 {
      $line = $contact['Contact'];

       $this->CSV->addRow($line);
 }

$filename='orders';
 echo  $this->CSV->render($filename);
```

what i want to make my excel sheet is like this 
as when i do in my view pages ..

```
      <table>

<tr>

    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Body</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($contacts as $contacts){?>
    <tr>

        <td> hello</td>
        <td> hello</td>
        <td> hello</td>
     </tr>
 }
    ?>
```

Comment: If it's just a CSV that is created here, I recommend https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-csvview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My recommendation is to use PHPExcel.

Here is what I have done:

I downloaded the PHPExcel files into Vendor folder.

My structure is now:

```
app 
  |---Vendor
        |----- PHPExcel
                   |----PHPExcel
                   |----PHPExcel.php
```

I needed to make my own forked changes to the PHPExcel for my own reasons. Hence I downloaded a copy instead of using the latest from repository with a package management solution like git submodules or composer. Feel free to use those.

Then I wrote my own Lib code in my cakephp app.

```
app 
  |---Lib
        |----- Print
                   |----Excel
                          |----SomeExcel.php
                          |----AnotherExcel.php
```

I wrote two classes `SomeExcel` and `AnotherExcel` because I needed to generate two different excel files.

Inside `SomeExcel` I wrote something like this:

```
require_once(APP . DS . 'Vendor' . DS . 'PHPExcel' . DS . 'PHPExcel.php');

class SomeExcel {
    private $yourOwnPrivateProperty;
    private $objPHPExcel;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->objPHPExcel    = new PHPExcel();
        $this->objPHPExcel->writeDebugLog = true;

        $this->_createFilename();

    }

    public function create() {
        // you have to study PHPExcel yourself and write this
        $this->_setFileProperties();
        // you have to study PHPExcel and write whatever you want
        $this->_createSheets();
        $result = $this->_save();

        if ($result) {
            return $this->_getAttachmentFormat();
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    protected function _save() {
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        /* I will create the folder inside the webroot outputfiles folder 
         * in case it does not exist.
         * I am not going to provide it here as it is not relevant to the question.
         * You need to write your own.
         */
        $this->_createFolder(); 
        try {
            $objWriter->save($this->outputPath . $this->filename);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected function _getAttachmentFormat() {
        return array(
            $this->filename => array(
                'file' => $this->outputPath . $this->filename,
                'mimetype' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                'contentId' => 'excelfile-for-something'
            )
        );
    }
```

The `AnotherExcel` class is similar.

Usually it is a controller action that triggers the generation of an Excel file. However, to obey the `FatModel-ThinController` principle, I have a Model method to do that.

So I have a controller action that is like this:

```
/**
 * print_to_excel method (testing only)
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function print_to_excel($id = null) {
    set_time_limit(120);
    $result = $this->SomeModel->printExcel($id);

    if (is_array($result)){
        $filename = key($result);
        $this->redirect('/outputfiles/Excel/' . $id . '/' . $filename);
    }
}
```

Inside my SomeModel, I have the following:

```
/**
 *
 * print excel file for said Quotation
 *
 * @param $id Quotation id
 * @throws NotExistException
 * @return boolean Return true if successful
 */
public function printExcel($id = null) {
    if (!$this->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid whatever'));
    }


    $data = $this->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('SomeModel.id' => $id),
    ));

    // do whatever you need to get the data you want printed in the Excel

    App::uses('SomeExcel', 'Lib/Print/Excel');

    $someExcel = new SomeExcel($data);

    return $someExcel->create();
}
```

This is my way of using Excel and CakePHP

It is one way, but not the only way.

I am also proud to tell you that this is the exact code I use for an enterprise app I wrote for a major telco company to do their own internal digital paperwork.

It is used by at least 10 people in that company.

Comment: I had tried your code...but can't pass to it. It says that address print_to_excel was not found. Do I still need to create a View for this? How do I populate it with mySQL query? Since I have noticed that it passed only Id. Thanks..

Comment: @never My code is not complete. I have left out the parts that are not important to help the original poster mynameisbutt. However, I believe that the answer alone should be sufficient. YOu do need to make your own decisions about things like what controller or model to use. In my case, I have a model called Quotation that needs to be printed out as an excel. Hence my controller related code is inside quotations controller and the model related code inside Quotation. In other words, you CANNOT use my code copy-paste with no modifications. You need to make contextual changes.