# Cakephp 2.3.0, CsvHelper is not generating download pop-up in online but works in localhost

Tags: php, excel, cakephp, csv, cakephp-2.3

I am using Cakephp 2.3.0, CsvHelper class to download the .csv excel file. I followed the following link to achive it - [cakephp excel/csv export component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298741/cakephp-excel-csv-export-component)

Everything works fine in localhost but when I try online I wont get the download pop up rather I get the output in the browser itself. Can any one please help me figure out this.

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Why not using [CsvView](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-csvview) then? A helper is pretty much an outdated concept for such a different representational format. also using csv view you can leverage the response class to force downloading etc.

Answer (score 1):

I used like this and their views i put a link to download csv

```
function export(){
$results=array();//containing result data
$excludePaths = array(); // Exclude all id fields
$_extract = $this->CsvView->prepareExtractFromFindResults($results, $excludePaths);
$_header = $this->CsvView->prepareHeaderFromExtract($_extract, $customHeaders);
$_serialize = 'results';
$this->response->download($filename);
        $this->viewClass = 'CsvView.Csv';
        $this->set(compact('results', '_serialize', '_header', '_extract'));
}
```