# How to show dates in csv file?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, csv

I am using a CSV helper to export data into csv file using cakephp,I have two table where there's relation between two table.after data from database,I want csv file what I am exactly getting in my view.Date fields showing ######,and column is showing database.I am using helper from the url below :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298741/cakephp-excel-csv-export-component
```

my controller code is  :

```
function download()
   {
        $tile=$this->Tile->find('first',array(
        ));
        $this->set('tile',$tile);
        $this->layout = null;
        $this->autoLayout = false;
        Configure::write('debug', '0');
   }
```

Finally My view code is :

```
$line= $tile[0]['Tile'];
 $this->CSV->addRow(array_keys($line));
 foreach ($tile as $tiles)
 {
       $line = $tiles;
       $this->CSV->addRow($line);
 }
 $filename='report';
 echo  $this->CSV->render($filename);
```

By using this script,I am getting the value in CSV something like below:

```
    id | emp_id | date |
=========================
    1  | 1      | ######
=========================
    2  | 2      | #####
```

But I want my report something like

```
   SL |  emp_name | date
==============================
   1  |    Amit   | 2014-01-01
==============================
   2  |    Robbie | 2014-01-02
```

Comment: I would just use https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-csvview - and the date would work right away (i bet).

Comment: expand date column in excel

Comment: Expand column is not programming solution - Anubhav

Comment: I will try,thanks for your answer.Hope it will help me---mark